# Is it possible to control the network connection type on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, networking

as topic, I want switch the network connection from 3G or WIFI via iPhone SDK , does it is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You can file a feature enhancement at Apple's [bug report site](http://bugreporter.apple.com/). If you're trying to do testing, go the device's Settings app and switch off WiFi to force 3G/EDGE service.